# Issues with initialising Redux in React while using mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to learn some redux. Component I'm working on is a simble `<div>` based button that - when clicked - passes value as a parameter to the dispatch, so it can be displayed later someplace else.

After following both documentation and tutorials over the web I came up with the following code:

**main app container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import configureStore from './../store/configureStore.js'
import Input from './input.js'

let store = configureStore()

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Input />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

**button container**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import printOut from './../actions/actions.js'
import InputComponent from './../components/inputComponent.js'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        onClick: (input) => dispatch(printOut(input))
    }
}

const Input = connect(mapDispatchToProps)(InputComponent)

export default Input
```

**button component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

class Input extends Component {
    render() { 
        return (
            <div style={style} onClick={this.props.onClick('lala')}>Button!</div>
        )
    }
}
Input.PropTypes = {
    onClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
const style = {
    height: 30, 
    width: 100, 
    backgroundColor: '#ff4068'
}

export default Input
```

Application breaks. I got this from the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions2.default) is not a function
    at Object.onClick (index.js:33683)
    at Input.render (index.js:33743)
    (...)
index.js:22443 The above error occurred in the <Input> component:
    in Input (created by Connect(Input))
    in Connect(Input) (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App
```

From what little I understood, there are some issues with `button component` and the way I'm trying to pass the param to props. So I tried to change it a little and added a function to handle that before render.

```
...
onClick(input) {
    return this.props.onClick(input)
}
render() {
    return (
        <div style={style} onClick={onClick('lala')}>Button!</div>
    )
}
...
```

The error I get this time is `onClick is not defined`. Oh, ok. I forgot `this` keyword before calling this new function. So I add it to the component and now I have

```
<div style={style} onClick={this.onClick('lala')}>Button!</div>
```

But the error being returned didn't really changed - it's again the original error of `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions2.default) is not a function`

I'm starting to run out of ideas now. Could someone please tell me how what my be the issue here? 
`Help me Stack Overflow, you're my only hope!` to quote timeless classic.

Comment: can you update the code with inputComponent.js ?

Comment: It's there: button component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you are importing printOut in properly? Shouldn't it be `import { printOut } from './../actions/actions.js'` ?

Then, first argument in connect is `mapStateToProps` and the second is `mapDispatchToProps` this is probably why you have `dispatch is not a function`.

Comment: Changing that import to what you propose resultet with `dispatch is not a function`, so I'm completely lost now.

Comment: can i see your actions file ?

Comment: @Aaqib here you go: 
`export const PRINT_OUT = 'PRINT_OUT'

export const printOut = (input) => {
    return {
        type: 'PRINT_OUT',
        input
    }
}`

Comment: first argument in `connect` is `mapStateToProps` and the second is `mapDispatchToProps` this is probably why you have `dispatch is not a function`

Comment: So, in case where I don't have `mapStateToProps` can I `null` it instead?
`const Input = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(InputComponent)`?

Comment: Oh, thank you for it kinda worked. Everything renders and `next state` is as it should be. only thing is I get this error now, but don't know how severe it is: `Warning: Expected onClick listener to be a function, instead got a value of object type.
    in div (created by Input)
    in Input (created by Connect(Input))
    in Connect(Input) (created by App)
    in Provider (created by App)
    in App`

Comment: Anyways, could you edit your answer with `mapStateToProps` comment, so I could accept it?

Comment: Yes, `null` or `undefined` in place of mapStateToProps. Regarding the new error - you have `onClick={this.props.onClick('lala')}` and it will invoke the function immedietelly and return something else in `onClick`, not the function. So you need to wrap it for example in another function `onClick={() => this.props.onClick('lala')}` which in fact will create new function everytime, but it is the fastest solution and in small apps the performance overhead isn't so bad. You can read about it for example here: https://medium.com/@machnicki/handle-events-in-react-with-arrow-functions-ede88184bbb

Answer (score 2):

You are importing InputComponent:

```
import InputComponent from './../components/inputComponent.js'
```

but inside button component you are exporting it as `Input`:

```
export default Input
```

so change InputComponent with :

```
import Input from './../components/inputComponent.js'
```

Use this for connect

```
export default connect(mapDispatchToProps)(Input)
```

Comment: It's not the issue sadly, but thank you never the less - I updated it for the consequence sake.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing 2 problems.

**1. Syntax problem in your import**

The following problem `Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _actions2.default) is not a function` is caused by the import of your actions.

Instead of

```
import printOut from './../actions/actions.js'
```

It should be

```
import { printOut } from './../actions/actions.js'
```

**2. You are incorrectly using `connect`**

`connect` accepts these two arguments with the following order:

1. `mapStateToProps`: contains the props you want to give to the component
2. `mapDispatchToProps`: contains the actions to dispatch

Even if you could call your action, there is no way the dispatch will happen because you call the `reducers` instead of the `dispatch`.

What you should do is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { printOut } from './../actions/actions.js';
import InputComponent from './../components/inputComponent.js';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onClick: (input) => dispatch(printOut(input))
  }
}

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(InputComponent);
```

You can read this documentation for more details: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#implementing-container-components